# How do you get to the fourth island without great slides in tiny wings?

Tags: tiny-wings

I have the x24 multiplier nest.  The next nest has an objective that requires you get to island 4 without any great slides.  This has turned out to be much harder than I anticipated and I'm wondering if I'm missing something simple.  I am trying to time my landings to hit the top of the hill before the dip, thus removing the chance of a great slide.  Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Always prevent a slide out of a valley by holding your finger down at the lowest part of the dip. But let your finger off after coming out of the valley to get some height and speed. When you hit the ground, again hold your finger down to prevent a slide. Repeat.

Basically, you're letting your finger off at the very last moment of leaving a valley and holding it down on the way in to prevent a slide.

Comment: This is pretty much the strategy that worked for me. Additionally, try to hit blue coins whenever possible - those little boosts can make a big difference.

Comment: @sjohnston absolutely.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks.  I was trying to time the landing, but it always killed my momentum.  Doing it your way I could keep the speed up and I did it on my second try with no issues.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, since it's Island 4, I don't think you need to go high at all. I believe what I did was abuse the fact that if you don't leave the ground by any significant distance, you won't end up with any great slides. So basically, just keep very close to the ground by keeping your finger glued to the screen. Since it's just island 4, you should be able to reach it this way.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I must be doing this wrong. Nighttime comes far too quickly when I try doing it this way.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was when I pressed down on the hill and went flying before I landed I would drop my bird and keep doing that and it worked it depends on how good you are with the jumps to see if your timing is just right good luck!

Answer (score -2):

Video Tutorial www.youtube.com/orangeanoying (I will have them posted soon=) )
It is actually really hard I gave up on. If you iPod is jailbroken You can use this

1st-Have SBSettings (Not Required but recommended) and ifile (Required)

2ed-Go Into SBSettings and Select MORE

3rd-Scroll down to App Folders and look for Tiny Wings

4th-Click it and remember The Path it shold say something like...
 /private/var/mobile/Applications/B695... (Just remember the first 4 Num/Leters

5th- Get Out of SBSettings and Go to Ifile then Click in this order
 /var/mobile/Applications

6th- You will see a bunch of numbered files look at the 4 Numbers or letters you had and open the folder

7th-Open Library and then Preferences There should only be 1 File in there so Click it and then Click Property List Viewer

8th- Change your achevements and other things Just not the long list of codes